# Update the state of a UISwitch when pressed in a TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiswitch

I have an iOS application that needs to turn on/off lights remotely. The app gets the data for the lights from parse.com and builds a tableview with every individual cell showing the name of the light and a UISwitch. I want to know how to change the boolean value stored on parse.com when I switch on or off one of the lights. The problem is that the IBAction used by the switch is not boolean and I cannot write and if statement that updates the value of the light is the switch is pressed. I have created the IBaction in my cell class and hoped that could be used by the tableviewcontroller class.

Here is part of my tableviewcontroller class

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell:RelayCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as RelayCell

    let label:PFObject = self.labelArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject //create the object label

    cell.relayTextField.text = label.objectForKey("text") as String //put the text in the labeltextField

    if (label.objectForKey("switch") as NSObject == 1) {
        //cell.mySwitch = true    //turn the switch on depending on the boolean value in switchColumn
        cell.mySwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }
    else{
        //cell.mySwitch = false    //turn the switch on depending on the boolean value in switchColumn
        cell.mySwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }
    return cell
}
```

This code shows the state of each independent switch however, what I want now is to be able to press on each independent button on the app and change the value on the online database.

Could you help me out since I haven't found anything online.

```
class RelayCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var relayTextField: UITextField!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
   relayTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
   relayTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
   relayTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}

  override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

 @IBAction func switchChangedState(sender: UISwitch) {
 }

}
```

This is my RelayCell class that is used by the tableView method in the tableViewController class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle this is to add a callback property to `RelayCell` and to call the callback from `switchChangedState`:

```
class RelayCell: UITableViewCell {

    typealias SwitchCallback = (Bool) -> Void
    var switchCallback: SwitchCallback?

    @IBAction func switchChangedState(sender: UISwitch) {
        switchCallback?(sender.on)
    }

    // ... rest of RelayCell
}
```

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, set the cell's callback:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:RelayCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as RelayCell

    cell.switchCallback = { [weak self] (switchIsOn) in
        self?.setSwitchValue(switchIsOn, forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
        Void()
    }

    // ... rest of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
    return cell
}
```

Then you can do whatever you need in `setSwitchValue:forRowAtIndexPath:`, which is a method you add to your table view controller class:

```
private func setSwitchValue(switchIsOn: Bool, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("row \(indexPath.row) switch on-ness is now \(switchIsOn)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UISwitch has "on" property, use it to get the boolean value for current state.

Comment: what I want is to know how to use the IBaction function from the tableViewController class. I know the UISwitch has an on property and have used that the tell me the row at which a switch is on and print it. I want to print the row of a switch that changes state when pressed.

Comment: "delegate" is your answer.